# How to replace column values based on other columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Assume, I have a data frame such as

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({'visitor':['A','B','C','D','E'],
                   'col1':[1,2,3,4,5],
                   'col2':[1,2,4,7,8],
                   'col3':[4,2,3,6,1]})
```

| visitor | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 4 |
| B | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| C | 3 | 4 | 3 |
| D | 4 | 7 | 6 |
| E | 5 | 8 | 1 |

For each row/visitor, (1) First, if there are any identical values, I would like to keep the 1st value of each row then replace the rest of identical values in the same row with NULL such as

| visitor | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | NULL | 4 |
| B | 2 | NULL | NULL |
| C | 3 | 4 | NULL |
| D | 4 | 7 | 6 |
| E | 5 | 8 | 1 |

Then (2) keep rows/visitors with more than 1 value such as
**Final Data Frame**

| visitor | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | NULL | 4 |
| C | 3 | 4 | NULL |
| D | 4 | 7 | 6 |
| E | 5 | 8 | 1 |

Any suggestions? many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `series.duplicated` along the columns axis to identify the duplicates, then mask the duplicates using `where` and filter the rows where the sum of non-duplicated values is greater than 1

```
s = df.set_index('visitor')
m = ~s.apply(pd.Series.duplicated, axis=1)

s.where(m)[m.sum(1).gt(1)]
```

---

```
         col1  col2  col3
visitor                  
A           1   NaN   4.0
C           3   4.0   NaN
D           4   7.0   6.0
E           5   8.0   1.0
```

Comment: hi Sharma, Can you kindly explain what ~s. is? This is my 1st time see this. Don't know what it means in pandas. many thanks

Comment: @DaCard `~` is the negation operator so basically  `~(s.apply(pd.Series.duplicated, axis=1))` will help you identify the non-duplicate values per row.

Comment: thank you for your quick response. Appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

Let us try `mask` with `pd.Series.duplicated`, then `dropna` with `thresh`

```
out = df.mask(df.apply(pd.Series.duplicated,1)).dropna(thresh = df.shape[1]-1)
Out[321]: 
  visitor  col1  col2  col3
0       A     1   NaN   4.0
2       C     3   4.0   NaN
3       D     4   7.0   6.0
4       E     5   8.0   1.0
```